# How to get the index of global variables in PHP-Parser

Tags: php, debugging, php-parser

I'm using [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) to build the AST. Then I want to reach the index of Global variables such as `$_POST['firstname']` , so I want to reach the index `firstname` and get it. How to reach the index of global variables, for example;

test

```
<?php 

$nameValue = $_POST['firstname'];
?>
```

AST Result:

```
array( 0: Stmt_Expression( expr: Expr_Assign( var: Expr_Variable( name: nameValue ) expr: Expr_ArrayDimFetch( var: Expr_Variable( name: _POST ) dim: Scalar_String( value: firstname ) ) ) ) )
```

So how to reach the index `firstname` and store it in variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your previous code in [How to use PHP-Parser to get the global variables name and change it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468224/how-to-use-php-parser-to-get-the-global-variables-name-and-change-it) and the code I posted as the answer.

Once you have identified that the node your looking at is a type `ArrayDimFetch`, and the variable name is of interest (such as `_POST` in this code), then you can output the `dim` node (the dimension I assume) value...

```
$traverser->addVisitor(new class extends NodeVisitorAbstract {
    public function leaveNode(Node $node) {
        if ($node instanceof Node\Expr\ArrayDimFetch
            && $node->var instanceof Node\Expr\Variable
            && $node->var->name === '_POST'
            ) {
                echo $node->dim->value;
            }
    }

});
```

**Update:**

After a bit more investigation, the above is fairly strict in that it assumes the index is a literal.  To make this more flexible, you can use the functionality in the pretty printer which allows the output of a node instead.  So the

```
echo $node->dim->value;
```

could be replaced by

```
$prettyPrinter = new PhpParser\PrettyPrinter\Standard;
echo $prettyPrinter->prettyPrintExpr($node->dim);
```

So if your code had `$_POST['a'."b"]` in it, this would correctly output `'a' . "b"`/